# Log in using custom external provider - ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, hybrid-mobile-app

Bottom line, I want to create a new provider for logging in to my web.

The big picture.
We are developing hybrid mobile application using ASP.Net MVC5 (with angular on front).

The entire application is based on web view except of the log in page.
The user can log in using his Facebook and Google account. This is done 100% by the native application (we have to do that way in order to invoke the mobile app and not the browser i.e open the Facebook/Google mobile application).
After the native application get the confirmation from the external provider it should log in to my website.

I had 2 ideas of doing it. The first was that the native application will send me(the ASP web application) the user email address (using Restful service) and some encrypted data, I will decode and validate it and if everything alright I'll sign in the user and return the authentication cookie.
The second idea was to do it in 2 steps, the native app will send the username and a token, then I (the ASP web application) will send back the token and receive an answer if the token is genuine and valid. If it is, then I will log in the user and return an authentication cookie.

In both ways I have 2 problems:

1. I don't know how to sign in a user with no username/password or Facebook/Google. How do I do it?
2. I don't know how to manually return authentication cookie.

The real problem is that until now I've only used the identity feature in the classic way.

Thanks from advance,
Shaul

Comment: You should follow this tutorial here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on

Comment: I already did this tutorial A to Z. The problem now is that the authentication part is manged by the Native Application.